# Can't make the TFS build fail after custom logic runs

Tags: nunit, tfsbuild

I've written some custom logic to get NUnit tests into a TFS build. It's all working beautifully except when the tests don't pass the build is partially succeeded rather than failed. Anyone know how I can tell it to fail?

Here's what I'm trying:

```
<BuildStep Message="Integration Tests Passed"
   Condition="$(TestsResult)  == 'True'"
   TeamFoundationServerUrl="$(TeamFoundationServerUrl)"
   BuildUri="$(BuildUri)"
   Id="$(IntegrationTestsStepId)"
   Status="Succeeded" />
<BuildStep Message="Integration Tests FAILED"
   Condition="$(TestsResult) != 'True'"
   TeamFoundationServerUrl="$(TeamFoundationServerUrl)"
   BuildUri="$(BuildUri)"
   Id="$(IntegrationTestsStepId)"
   Status="Failed"
   CompilationStatus="Failed"
   TestStatus="Failed"/>
<!-- If NUnit failed it's time to error out -->
<Error Condition="$(TestsResult) != 'True'" Text="Unit Tests Failed" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was the `<SetBuildProperties>` that was the magic:

```
    <SetBuildProperties TeamFoundationServerUrl="$(TeamFoundationServerUrl)"
                        BuildUri="$(BuildUri)"
                        CompilationStatus="Failed"
                        TestStatus="Failed"
                        Condition="'$(TestsResult)' != 'True'">
</SetBuildProperties>


<Error Condition="'$(TestsResult)'!='True'" Text="Smoke Tests Failed" />
<SetBuildProperties TeamFoundationServerUrl="$(TeamFoundationServerUrl)"
                        BuildUri="$(BuildUri)"
                        CompilationStatus="Succeeded"
                        TestStatus="Succeeded"
                        Condition="'$(TestsResult)' != 'False'">
</SetBuildProperties>
```

I think it boils down to needing to signal the **CompilationStatus** and the **TestStatus**

Answer (score 1):

This is the default behaviour for Unit Tests in Team Build. We use MStest rather than nUnit so this might not work but you are setting $(TestResult) so it should be OK. If you have VS2008 SP1 installed on your build server you can add the following line to your TfsBuild.proj (in the additional properties section) and it should fail the build

`<TreatTestFailureAsBuildFailure>true</TreatTestFailureAsBuildFailure>`

Comment: Unfortunately we don't have SP1 installed on our box so that attribute doesn't work for us. In the end we just had to settle for partial failure.